# Android: Parse + Facebook integration

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am working on Parse and Facebook integration with reference to the tutorial https://github.com/ParsePlatform/IntegratingFacebookTutorial/tree/master/IntegratingFacebookTutorial-Android, and come across headache problems that would like someone who can offer advice.

### LoginActivity.java

```
OnCreate
....
// Check if there is a currently logged in user and it's linked to a Facebook account.
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if ((currentUser != null) && ParseFacebookUtils.isLinked(currentUser)) 
        {
            // Go to the user info activity
            showUserDetailsActivity();
        }


  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
  {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }

  public void onLoginClick(View v) 
  {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "", "Logging in...", true);

    List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList(
              "public_profile",
              "user_friends",
              "email",
              "user_birthday"
            );

    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() 
    {
      @Override
      public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) 
      {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        if (user == null) 
        {
          Log.d(Msg, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
          Utilities.custom_toast(LoginActivity.this, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.", "gone!", "short");
        } 
        else if (user.isNew()) 
        {
          Log.d(Msg, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
          Utilities.custom_toast(LoginActivity.this, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!", "gone!", "short");
          showUserDetailsActivity();
        } 
        else 
        {
          Log.d(Msg, "User logged in through Facebook!");
          Utilities.custom_toast(LoginActivity.this, "User logged in through Facebook!", "gone!", "short");
          showUserDetailsActivity();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private void showUserDetailsActivity() 
  {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, UserDetails.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }
```

### UserDetails.java

```
@Override  
    protected void onResume() 
    {  
        super.onResume();  
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) 
        {
          // Check if the user is currently logged and show any cached content
          updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
        } 
        else 
        {
          // If the user is not logged in, go to the activity showing the login view.
          startLoginActivity();
        }
    }
    private void makeMeRequest() 
    {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() 
        {
              @Override
              public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) 
              {
                if (jsonObject != null) 
                {
                    JSONObject userProfile = new JSONObject();
                    try 
                    {
                        userProfile.put("facebookId", jsonObject.getLong("id"));
                        userProfile.put("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));

                        if (jsonObject.getString("gender") != null)
                            userProfile.put("gender", jsonObject.getString("gender"));

                        if (jsonObject.getString("email") != null)
                            userProfile.put("email", jsonObject.getString("email"));

                        // Save the user profile info in a user property
                        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                        currentUser.put("User", userProfile);
                        currentUser.saveInBackground();

                        // Show the user info
                        updateViewsWithProfileInfo();
                    } 
                    catch (JSONException e) 
                    {
                        Log.d(TAG,"Error parsing returned user data. " + e);
                    }
                } 
                else if (graphResponse.getError() != null) 
                {
                  switch (graphResponse.getError().getCategory()) 
                  {
                    case LOGIN_RECOVERABLE:
                        Utilities.custom_toast(UserDetails.this, "Authentication error: " + graphResponse.getError(), "gone!", "short");
                      break;

                    case TRANSIENT:
                        Utilities.custom_toast(UserDetails.this, "Transient error. Try again" + graphResponse.getError(), "gone!", "short");
                        Log.d(TAG,"Transient error. Try again. " + graphResponse.getError());
                      break;

                    case OTHER:
                        Utilities.custom_toast(UserDetails.this, "Some other error: " + graphResponse.getError(), "gone!", "short");
                        Log.d(TAG,"Some other error: " + graphResponse.getError());
                      break;
                  }
                }
              }
        });
        request.executeAsync();
      }

      private void updateViewsWithProfileInfo()      
      {
        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser.has("profile")) 
        {
          JSONObject userProfile = currentUser.getJSONObject("profile");
          try 
          {
            if (userProfile.has("name")) 
            {
              userNameView.setText(userProfile.getString("name"));
            } else 
            {
              userNameView.setText("no name");
            }

            if (userProfile.has("gender")) {
              userGenderView.setText(userProfile.getString("gender"));
            } else {
              userGenderView.setText("no gender");
            }

            if (userProfile.has("email")) {
              userEmailView.setText(userProfile.getString("email"));
            } else {
              userEmailView.setText("no email");
            }

          } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error parsing saved user data.");
          }
        } 
        else
        {
            Utilities.custom_toast(UserDetails.this, "no profile!", "gone!", "short");
        }
      }

      public void onLogoutClick(View v) 
      {
        logout();
      }

      private void logout() 
      { 
        ParseUser.logOut(); // Log the user out
        startLoginActivity(); // Go to the login view
      }

      private void startLoginActivity() 
      {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
      }
```

## Question:

I have tried run the app as a new user:
1. when press the login button, it process and pop up "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!" However, after logged in, it turns to the `UserDetails` page, but reports via a toast "no profile!" , ie the currentUser has no info inside.  What is going wrong here?

2. Why there is no permission page popup when login despite it got "email" permission?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you properly initializing the ParseFacebook utils? You can follow the exact steps you have to do to integrate Facebook with your Parse app in the official documentation: https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#fbusers

Comment: As far as I remember email is always authorized, you should see an error for birthday I guess